# gulp 4 dependencies and plugins

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, dependencies, gulp

Due to issues with gulp 3 forcing my tasks to run concurrently, I have starting investigating **gulp 4** with the hope of exploiting its gulp.series and gulp.parallel functions but I have hit a wall.

After some research I came across the **undertaker-forward-reference** plugin that should allow me to have something like:

```
var gulp            = require('gulp');
var FwdRef          = require('undertaker-forward-reference');

gulp.registry(FwdRef());

gulp.task('biggie', gulp.series('smalls'));

gulp.task('smalls', function(cb){
  console.log("This is awesome");
  cb();
});
```

where task 'biggie' depends on task 'smalls' but smalls is defined lower in in the gulp file. I get the following error:

> ```
> assert.js:86
> ```
>
> throw new assert.AssertionError({
>           ^
>   AssertionError: Task never defined: smalls

What am I getting wrong here....
P.S. I am new to this so please be kind.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define "smalls" first. like...

```
var gulp            = require('gulp');

var FwdRef          = require('undertaker-forward-reference');

gulp.registry(FwdRef());

gulp.task('smalls', function(cb){
  console.log("This is awesome");
  cb();
});

gulp.task('biggie', gulp.series('smalls'));
```